# Random "silent" crash when running a math kernel in terminal for a long time

Tags: kernel, linux, scripting

I sometimes use Mathematica to run very long calculations in the terminal (Debian). To do this I use the command:

```
math -script (filename)
```

Now after several hours of running, the kernel just randomly shuts down, without outputting any error message to the terminal. The problem persists in every Mathematica version I have tried: 9.0, 10.0 and 10.1.

Is there a way I can find out what causes the crash? Maybe some logging file or something? I have tried looking through my ~/.Mathematica/Logs folder but it's empty.

Comment: How reproducible is this?  Does it happen every time?  Could you put in commands to the script to write to a file at every step so that you can see what is happening when it crashes?

Comment: It happens everytime. The script does the same short calculation for randomly generated input paramters 10^5 times. After some time, it just crashes. Memory usage is small, so that is definitely not the problem.