# After some calculations, Mathematica forgets previous results

Tags: evaluation, warning-messages, kernel

After I do some calculations, the next calculation often just returns the previous declared result as a name and I have to start all over.

My "parallel kernel configuration" is set to "manual" with only 1 kernel, "Default Kernel" and "Notebook's Kernel" are both set to "Local", the "Notebook's Default Context" is set to "Global" without either of the two boxes below, "Unique to this notebook" & "Unique to each cell group", checked.

There is nothing special about the calculations so I'm not sure a MWE is relevant - I calculate two series, normalize them, and then divide them. The latter part, referencing the two normal series, is what relies on the previous results. Instead of a quotient I just get the names of the two series.

Is there anything else I can provide to help with an answer?

PS. Possibly related.... Is there a way to check my installation? Something like a "make check" or a "run_testsuite()"?

Comment: Is the kernel crashing? Do the outputs go back to numbering from 1?

Comment: Oh, yes they do! Sorry I know almost nothing about Mathematica....

Comment: You may be running out of memory. Mathematica may be interpreting your input in some way you don't expect and trying to create a huge object.

Comment: Hhhmmmm... I understand what you are saying. Are there logs written somewhere? I have 16GB, a 80 GB swap*file* and nothing running except small Midori browser with one window and two tabs... On a year old MacBook Pro. These kid of 'crashes' do not show up in /var/log....

Comment: If you provide the code, I expect someone will offer help

Comment: Here is a guy who has a similar problem, and no answer yet: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98619/random-silent-crash-when-running-a-math-kernel-in-terminal-for-a-long-time  I'll work on getting the code downsized....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Kernel is indeed crashing. If you're not doing any graphics, it could be that the computations are running out of memory. If there is graphical output, you may also be running into graphics card issues.

Since the problem seems to involve series, maybe you can first try to reduce the number of terms in the series and see if the calculation goes through.

For the last part of the question, you may try the following:

- Open the menu `Mathematica > About Mathematica...`
- click on `System Information`
- at the bottom of the panel that appears, click `Benchmark with WolframMark...`

See also the [Benchmarking Package](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Benchmarking/tutorial/Benchmark). This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but it's the closest to a test suite I can think of.